# Intersect Select Query in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

I want to have customers intersection in two mdx querys.

1.

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Cs] ON 0
 ,NonEmpty([Customers].[Customer].MEMBERS) ON 1
FROM [sfe cube]
WHERE 
  (
    [Calend].[Period].&[201506]
   ,[Customers].[BP Territory].&[38UZ1]
   ,[Materials].[Brand].&[Coca-Cola]
  );
```

2.

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Cs] ON 0
 ,NonEmpty([Customers].[Customer].MEMBERS) ON 1
FROM [sfe cube]
WHERE 
  (
    [Calend].[Period].&[201506]
   ,[Customers].[BP Territory].&[38UZ1]
   ,[Materials].[Brand].&[Fanta Orange CSD]
  );
```

My attempted `mdx` script:

```
SELECT
 {} ON COLUMNS,
INTERSECT(
 (  Select [Measures].[Cs] on 0,
    nonempty([Customers].[Customer].members) on 1
    from [sfe cube]
    WHERE ([Calend].[Period].&[201506]
    ,[Customers].[BP Territory].&[38UZ1]
    ,[Materials].[Brand].&[Coca-Cola])
 )
,
(   Select [Measures].[Cs] on 0,
    nonempty([Customers].[Customer].members) on 1
    from [sfe cube]
    WHERE ([Calend].[Period].&[201506]
    ,[Customers].[BP Territory].&[38UZ1]
    ,[Materials].[Brand].&[Fanta Orange CSD]))

) ON ROWS      
FROM [sfe cube]
```

When I run query there is a error :

> Subselect only support axis COLUMNS.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement something like this for the `AND` logic:

```
WITH 
  SET [YourSet] AS 
    NonEmpty
    (
      NonEmpty
      (
        {[Customers].[Customer].MEMBERS}
       ,{[Materials].[Brand].&[Fanta Orange CSD]}
      )
     ,{[Materials].[Brand].&[Coca-Cola]}
    ) 
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Cs] ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY [YourSet] ON 1
FROM [sfe cube]
WHERE 
  (
    [Calend].[Period].&[201506]
   ,[Customers].[BP Territory].&[38UZ1]
  );
```

A different variant (that is I like better) using `Exists` is detailed in this post:

[MDX query to calculate measure with AND condition by members from same dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913457/mdx-query-to-calculate-measure-with-and-condition-by-members-from-same-dimension/30913891#30913891)

I like sourav's idea to us `intersect`. I think his script can be simplified slightly to this:

```
WITH 
  SET CommonCustomers AS 
    Intersect
    (
      NonEmpty
      (
        [Customers].[Customer].MEMBERS
       ,[Materials].[Brand].&[Coca-Cola]
      )
     ,NonEmpty
      (
        [Customers].[Customer].MEMBERS
       ,[Materials].[Brand].&[Fanta Orange CSD]
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Cs]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    CommonCustomers ON ROWS
FROM [sfe cube]
WHERE 
  (
    [Calend].[Period].&[201506]
   ,[Customers].[BP Territory].&[38UZ1]
  );
```

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree. In case `[Measures].[Cs]` is not the default member in the "Measures" dimension, it would pick up all the cells which are non-empty w.r.t to the default measure, not this measure. So there is a chance of selecting lesser or more customers. Hence I feel if the measure is not specified in the second argument of `NonEmpty`, the filtering would be arbitrary(or on the basis of default measure, which is arbitrarily chosen by the engine).

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti interesting - The inclusion of `NON EMPTY` should cover this possibility?

Comment: `NON EMPTY`  is bad for performance?! Please add some references to articles backing this up? Or do you mean in my specific script the use of `NON EMPTY` is bad for performance?

Comment: Speaking in general, it should be avoided as it iterates through the entire rowset to hunt for empty tuples. If the empty tuples can be reduced in `NonEmpty`, it is better I feel. Also, for your reference [1](http://www.sqlserverdatamining.com/OLAPPapers/MDX%20Performance%20Hintsv2.htm) , [2](http://thatmsftbiguy.com/nonemptymdx/) It is drastically slower than `NonEmpty`. In the end, it's my personal opinion. You are entitled to your own :)

Comment: Also, how will `NON EMPTY` handle the possibility of it returning more or less customers if the default measure is different from `[Measures].[Cs]`?

Comment: No worries Sourav. `NonEmpty` is a great performance tool. It is different to Non Empty. With respect though I would not say `Non Empty` should generally be avoided  - there are many many occasions where users do not want to see empty rows or columns.

Comment: Yes of course. But it should not be unnecessarily used. I rest my case.

Comment: Code works perfectly. If I want to intersect 10 sets? I need to use construction of intersect (set1,(intersect (set2,(intersect(... 10 times? Or there is a better solution ?

Comment: @ВиталийАщеулов unfortunately both of the functions `NonEmpty` and `Intersect` take just two arguments so _yes_ you will need to nest several times. On the plus side this intersection operation is associative so the order than you nest is not important you will always get the same result.

Comment: Thank you. And do you know is there any variant to create a calculated member in bids that automatically calculate in result intersection of all drilled down arguments. For example I drill by brand that consist of 5 items. And in total I have intersection result. Or when drill down other item of material dimension for example package size - I have in result intersection by package size. Or it is impossible?

Comment: You can just wrap your set code with the Aggregate function (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145524.aspx) or the Sum function (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145484.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax has gone haywire! Check the syntax for `INTERSECT` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms144943.aspx).

The way I would get the "common" customers would be as follows:

```
WITH SET CommonCustomers AS

INTERSECT(

            NonEmpty(
                        [Customers].[Customer].members, 
                        (
                            [Calend].[Period].&[201506],
                            [Customers].[BP Territory].&[38UZ1],
                            [Materials].[Brand].&[Coca-Cola]
                        ) * [Measures].[Cs]
                    )
            ,

            NonEmpty(
                        [Customers].[Customer].members, 
                        (
                            [Calend].[Period].&[201506],
                            [Customers].[BP Territory].&[38UZ1],
                            [Materials].[Brand].&[Fanta Orange CSD]
                        ) * [Measures].[Cs]
                    )

        )

SELECT {} ON COLUMNS,
CommonCustomers ON ROWS
FROM [sfe cube]
```